# Exceção "Property 'System.DateTime Date' is not defined for type 'System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime]' (Parameter 'property')"

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Atualizei o EF Core para a versão 3.1.6 e estou recebendo essa exceção quando executo um teste.

Os métodos que causam isso são estes dois:

```
public static IQueryable<CashoutRequest> WhereTransferOrInstitutionTransferStartDate
(
    this IQueryable<CashoutRequest> cashoutRequests, 
    DateTime? date
)
{
    if (date == null) return cashoutRequests;

    var startDate = date.Value.Date;

    return cashoutRequests.Where(cashoutRequest => 
        cashoutRequest.Transfer.CreatedAt.Date >= startDate
        || 
        cashoutRequest.InstitutionTransfer.CreatedAt.Date >= startDate
    );
}

public static IQueryable<CashoutRequest> WhereTransferOrInstitutionTransferEndDate
(
    this IQueryable<CashoutRequest> cashoutRequests, 
    DateTime? date
)
{
    if (date == null) return cashoutRequests;

    var endDate = date.Value.Date;

    return cashoutRequests.Where(cashoutRequest => 
        cashoutRequest.Transfer.CreatedAt.Date <= endDate
        || 
        cashoutRequest.InstitutionTransfer.CreatedAt.Date <= endDate
    );
}
```

Os campos `CreatedAt` não são `nullables`, é como se o Entity Framework Core os tornassem `nullables` na execução?

Entidades:

```
    public class CashoutRequest
        {
            public long Id { get; set; }
            public long? TransferId { get; set; }
            public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
            public DateTime? ReprovedAt { get; set; }
            public DateTime? ApprovedAt { get; set; }
            public DateTime? CanceledAt { get; set; }
            public Transfer Transfer { get; set; }
            public InstitutionTransfer InstitutionTransfer { get; set; }
}

public class Transfer
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
        public DateTime? ApprovedAt { get; set; }
        public DateTime? CanceledAt { get; set; }
        public DateTime? ReprovedAt { get; set; }
    }

public class InstitutionTransfer
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    public DateTime? ApprovedAt { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CanceledAt { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ReprovedAt { get; set; }
    public long? CashoutRequestId { get; set; }

    public CashoutRequest CashoutRequest { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Estava funcionando e parou de funcionar depois da atualização? Poste também a entidade `CashoutRequest`, `Transfer` e `InstitutionTransfer`?

Comment: Sim, parou de funcionar depois da atualização

Comment: @novic As entidades são bem grandes. Eu testei agora removendo o Date e funcionou. Agora vou pesquisar como fazer para comprar apenas a data

Comment: Qual banco que é? e tem o método EF (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.ef.functions?view=efcore-5.0) e https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbfunctions?view=efcore-5.0

Comment: talvez: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlserverdbfunctionsextensions.datefromparts?view=efcore-5.0#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_SqlServerDbFunctionsExtensions_DateFromParts_Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_DbFunctions_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Int32_

Comment: @novic É SQL Server

Comment: Sem as entidades fica difcil dizer!

Comment: @novic Coloquei as entidades

Comment: deve ser os `nullable` dos paramentos? faça a alteração `DateTime date` para `DateTime date` vai dar certo ai você tem que usar outra estratégia.

Comment: porque assim `startDate` esta diferente de `CreatedAt`, respectivamente Nullables e DateTime ... são diferentes

Comment: Outra coisa esse método não é necessário dessa forma! veja se você tem um construção Linq Builder é só copiar a ultima alteração e seguir em frente ...

Comment: O problema não é o parâmetro do método. Eu mudei a propriedade Date para Year e a exceção foi a mesma, mudando apenas a mensagem, referenciando a propriedade Year

Comment: é sim cara são diferentes, teste com a data sem ser nullable

Comment: mas você reparou que `DateTime? date` e você está usando essa variável para as comparações?

Comment: @LeandroAngelo Mas eu passo o date para startDate acessando o Value, então é uma variável DateTime

Quando eu tirei o .Date o teste passou